# Fetch only coefficients from an equation

Tags: c#, regex

I have an equation written as follows:

1st formula:  `(0.085+4.346*10^-5*((a^2)-(0^2))+0.0017228*(a-(0)))*2`
Coefficients are:
1) 0.085
2) 4.346*10^5
3) 0.0017228

2nd formula: `((0.208+0*d^3-0.00000434*d^2-0.00203*d)*2)`
Coefficients are:
1) 0.208
2) 0
3) -0.00000434
4) -0.00203

From the above formula mentioned I need a regular expressions written in C# to fetch coefficients mentioned above.

I tried the regular expression: `"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"`
returns good co-efficient s but not '0' as mentioned in the 2nd formula from above.

I tried the following code:

```
    string p = @"((0.208+0*d^3-0.00000434*d^2-0.00203*d)*2)";

     var result = Regex.Matches(p, @"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0).ToList();
     foreach(string item in result)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
     }
```

The result from above code:
0.208
-0.00000434 
-0.00203
(0 is missing here as 2nd co-efficient which is required.)

Comment: I don't think a RegEx is going to be good enough, you really need a parser, something that can break this down into a hierarchical structure.

Comment: Regex is a *regular language* parsing engine. This isn't a regular language issue, you're trying to use a spoon to knock in a nail

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. You *might* get this regex to work for these expressions, but it'll be a nightmare to fix in a few months when a new expression comes along that the regex can't quite support.  Use math parser library, such as mXparser.

Answer (score 0):

The desired output, specifically  `4.346*10^5`, would make this expression too complicated, and I also don't think a RegEx would be good enough, even though your original expression is just fine. We would then slightly simplify that to:

```
-?[0-9]*(?:\.?[0-9]+)?(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

and hopefully you are likely going to figure out how to output `4.346*10^5` or deal with/bypass that.

---

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"-?[0-9]*(?:\.?[0-9]+)?(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?";
        string input = @"0.085+4.346*10^-5*((a^2)-(0^2))+0.0017228*(a-(0)))*2
0.208+0*d^3-0.00000434*d^2-0.00203*d)*2)";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zHmjaU/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/zHmjaU/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.